# How to solve out Windows sound problems which occur only with some users?

Tags: windows, audio

My users use custom softphone system in Windows 10. Only some of them in some offices suffer from bad voice / audio problems. The users sometimes hear voices with bad quality.

My guess is that some other program, the computer model, the processor model etc can cause the problem.

Is there any common monitoring applications which users can install to their computers? Those monitoring applications should log any voice problems etc. Is Windows natively having this kind of programs?

Comment: This isn't a programming question per se, so it may get closed. I'll try to help.

1) The Windows audio subsystem (which includes mixing) runs at the highest level of user-mode. That's what enables music players to still sound good while  However, when the system is extremely taxed with other high priority processes and threads running at high or real-time priority, audio drops can happen. Use Task Manager to see if the system is at 100% CPU usage and look for offending non-system EXEs running in the details pane chewing up CPU usage

Comment: 2) Make sure you have the latest drivers and OS updates installed.

Comment: 3) Some video conferencing applications try to "go direct" via P2P but fallback to an Internet relay server when a direct connection isn't available. Use a tool like wireshark to see where the packets are going.  It's possible the some devices are going direct but others getting relayed.

Comment: 4) If these devices are on wifi, nothing makes audio and video conferencing suffer more than poor network connectivity. Validate these devices have a good wifi signal. This is quite common with folks working from home.  5)  Consider contacting the software vendor of this app. They can typically diagnose these issues by looking at logs and account activity.

Comment: @selbie You should know better than to post answers in the comment section. Especially for off topic questions that WILL get closed.